# Randomly test a web application à la android 'monkey'?

Tags: python, testing, web-applications, automated-tests

I'm writing a django web application, and I'm making unittests & selenium functional tests. However I'm paranoid that I'll miss something. I recently found out about [android's monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html), that AFAIK randomly presses buttons on your application and sees if it crashes.

Is there anything like this for html/web applications (that works on Linux)? Something that I can point at the webserver, and it'll try randomly submitting forms, changing a value here and there, and I can let it run for a while and see if there is some undiscovered code path that causes an error? I'd be interested in something that just does command line basic html (i.e. JS support not necessary), however if there's one that does in-browser testing, that'd be cool/interesting aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want "fuzz" testing tools. Have a look at a selection available for Python
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#Fuzz_Testing_Tools

Comment: Invalid link now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try gremlins.js, seems to be a good fit with your need

https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.